# How i can decide need nextPage or not for my listItems

Tags: java, pagination

questiton about pagination. My "StubServer" has method ->
`readAll(int limit, int offset)`. This method return sublist. Ok.
Question is how i can know hasNextPage or not.

I have to decide need or not next page WITHOUT knowledge about size of the list of all the elements.

Comment: What happens when offset is more than the records? Does it return null?

Comment: Based on the method signature there is not enough returned data from **an**  invocation to determine if there is a next page.  @i.net might be suggesting to call the method again, but with a different `offset`, to determine if there is any more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

If your `result` list has less than your `limit` then you have reached the end of list and shouldn't call the method any more.

```
int limit = 100;
int offset = 0;
do {
     list = readAll(limit, offset);
     int resultSize = list.count(); // Assuming some logic to count

     // do something with list

     // Check for list size vs requested items
     if(resultSize < limit) {
        // Exit loop when number of result retrieved was less than requested items
        break;
     }

     // Else just move on to next batch
     offset += limit;

} while (expression);
```